# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cities.schools_list_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel-5.4

How to display a city?

City.php

```
public function schools ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SchoolsList::class);
}
```

SchoolList.php

```
public function city ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
```

My Controller.php

```
public function index ()
{
    $inspectors_lists = SubmitApplication::latest()->where->get();
    return view('Admin.inspectors-list.all', compact('inspectors_lists'));
}
```

My Blade

```
<td>{{ $inspectors_list->school_lists->city->city_name }}</td>
```

But I get this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   cities.schools_list_id in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   cities where cities.`schools_list_id` = 1 and
>   cities .schools_list_id is not null) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\tvto\resources\views\Admin\inspectors-list\all.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your database. If the column schools_list_id exists in cities table

Answer (score 0):

I think **cities.schools_list_id** this field not available in your database name please check this.